# Can you execute raw MySQL queries on an empty migration in .Net core Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

That's basically my question. I know you can do it using  SQL server with the command SQL(the query) or fromsql()  and I want to do the same thing but with my MySQL database is it possible? I haven't found anything about it I figured it would be the same but with the function MySql but it tells me I'm using the namespace as a function

Answer (score 0):

FromSqlRaw (the non Raw form is deprecated) is not explicit to SQL Server. I can be used for MySQL.

You typically create a DbSet with a HasNoKey entity attribute.

```
// Result set mapping
public class Joke
{
    public string TheJoke { get; set; }
}

public class JokeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Joke> Jokes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=127.0.0.1;database=foo;user=root;password=secretpassword");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Joke>().HasNoKey();
    }
}
```

Then simply query the database using SQL.

```
List<Joke> jokes = await _ctx.Jokes.FromSqlRaw("select Text as TheJoke from joke").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you so much I found on the documentation that you can use the FromSqlRaw method but it didn't want to work for me I figured I was missing an extra step. I wanted to write some Raw queries on an empty migration

Comment: @Bryan Empty migration?